# Start webpack dev server without the building step

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Is there a way to start webpack devserver without running the build process?

I want it to just serve my static files that were already built. Here is my config:

```
   devServer: {
    port: 7171,
    inline: true,
    stats: 'errors-only',
    open: false,
    contentBase: path.resolve('static'),
    publicPath: '/app/site/',
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: '/app/site/index.dev.html'
    },
    proxy: {
      '/app/static': {
        target: 'http://localhost:7171',
        pathRewrite: {'static': 'site'}
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to skip the build process for webpack-dev-server as webpack needs the build process to properly compile the js files and link them to their dependencies.

Comment: but if they are static why the build process is required? I can build once and serve whenever I need (e2e tests is my scenario).

Comment: if you just need to serve static files, you might be better served by other solutions or just directly referencing the file in a publicly accessible end point. Webpack is slightly opinionated in favor of reducing configuration so it assumes a lot of things, including the assumption that the items it is building will need linking and or transformation or whatever else you add in your build process.

Comment: its a shame, because all the configurations are already there and serving via other lib would add another dependency :(

Comment: @vlio20 I would suggest that you keep using webpack since for production, the files are only built once during deploy so you dont have to worry about rebuilds happening all over the place eating up all your resources. not to mention some libraries like uglifier can optimize your code that will be served for production. is there a special reason why you want to skip the build process?

Comment: Sure, when developing the e2e specs it is not required to rebuild the app for each run of e2e (locally), so it doesn't make sense to build it each time. The build process takes 30 seconds which is a lot.

Comment: does it have a need to actually run the webpack dev server for the test? Maybe you can modify your test suite to just run a webpack build once before running the all the specs. webpack-dev-server should really only be used when you're actually trying to dev

Comment: I need it for loading static resources with some proxy as you can see in the code I posted